# Dynamically generate and access UITextField using tag in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I have a code of generating UITextField dynamically like this:

```
 UITextField *myTextfield;
    - (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIView* headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 640.0f, 0.0f)];
      //for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        myTextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60*i+20, 280, 45)];
        myTextfield.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Value: %d", section];
        myTextfield.enabled = NO;
        myTextField.tag = section;
        [headerView addSubview:myTextField];
    }
```

I also generated a **edit button** beside each of those textfields.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {        
        static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"cell1";
        cell = (ButtonCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ButtonCell"
                                                         owner:self options:nil];
            for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[ButtonCell class]])
                cell = (ButtonCell *)oneObject;

        }
        cell.msg_btn.tag = indexPath.section;
        cell.changecolor_btn.tag = indexPath.section;
        cell.picklist_btn.tag = indexPath.section;
        cell.adddelsubmenu_btn.tag = indexPath.section;
        cell.done_btn.tag = indexPath.section;

        [cell.msg_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(editEachTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        return cell;
}
```

Now I want to enable and access each of the textfields when I click one of those buttons . I'm using **tag** to access those textfields like this:

```
- (void) editEachTextField:(UIButton*)sender
{
  myTextfield = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:myTextfield.tag];
    myTextfield.enabled = YES;
    [myTextfield becomeFirstResponder];

    NSLog(@"Tag value of Textfield: %ld",(long)myTextfield.tag);
    NSString *text = [(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:myTextfield.tag] text];
    NSLog(@"Value: %@", text);
}
```

But whenever I click one of those button it returns tag value=**4** and the 4th textfield is enabled for editing. What's the problem?

Comment: Don't start at tag 0, it's used by default for every view. You should use tags 1..5 inclusive, not 0..4.

Answer (score 3):

You are taking `myTextfield.tag` value for enabling the text field instead of clicked button's tag.
The `myTextfield` points to the last allocated `UITextField` (Which has tag 4), that's why you are getting tag value as 4 and the last textfield is getting enabled.

Issue is with this code:

```
myTextfield = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:myTextfield.tag];
```

Change that to:

```
myTextfield = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:sender.tag];
```

**Note:**

Don't use same tag for button and textfield if both are placed in the same view. If done so, you can't ensure which object you'll be getting when the `viewWithTag` is used.

Comment: Ok, I changed the code accordingly and also tried `myTextfield.tag=sender.tag; myTextfield.enabled = YES;` but the 4th field is being enabled all time.

Comment: Can you show the button creating code? Why did you use `myTextfield.tag=sender.tag;` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextField *txtfield = (UITextField *)sender;
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)txtfield.tag);
```

Comment: This in itself isn't enough of an answer. You really need to add more to this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Solved it by myself with the help of @Midhun MP and @Cyrille.

```
UITextField *myTextfield;
    - (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIView* headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 640.0f, 0.0f)];
      //for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        myTextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60*i+20, 280, 45)];
        myTextfield.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Value: %d", section];
        myTextfield.enabled = NO;
        myTextField.tag = 400+section;
        [headerView addSubview:myTextField];
    }
```

and the button action selector:

```
- (void) editEachTextField:(UIButton*)sender
{
  myTextfield = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:400+sender.tag];
    myTextfield.enabled = YES;
    [myTextfield becomeFirstResponder];

    NSString *text = [(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:400+sender.tag] text];
    NSLog(@"Value: %@", text);
}
```